# VBA code to use a for loop across all sheets in a workbook to select the variable contents?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with multiple sheets, in each sheet I need to copy the same row contents to my master list. I have a code to get one cell value (which is N7) in each sheet to my master,

The problem is, in some sheets, the cell value to be get into master will be one cell , In other sheets, it will be two or more cells like (N7 TO N11)

How should I get this in to my master?
My current code is,

```
Dim DataFile As String
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Range("T3").Value
DataFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Range("C4").Select
For i = 1 To Workbooks(DataFile).Worksheets.Count
ActiveCell.Value = Workbooks(DataFile).Worksheets(i).Range("N7").Value
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next i
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: How you determine how many cells you want to copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work nicely, provided that you  change the `MasterFileSheetNameHere` to your sheet name

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyFromEachSheet()

    Dim CurrentWorkSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DataFile As Workbook
    Dim DataFileLastRow As Long
    Dim MasterFileSheet As Worksheet
    Dim MasterFileLastRow As Long
    Dim RangeToCopy As Range
    Dim DataFileRowCount As Long

    'Assuming that this scipt will be in your master file
                                            'Replace with youor sheet name
    Set MasterFileSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterFileSheetNameHere")

    Set DataFile = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MasterFileSheet.Range("T3").Value)

    For Each CurrentWorkSheet In DataFile.Sheets

        With MasterFileSheet
            MasterFileLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        End With

        With CurrentWorkSheet
            DataFileLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
        End With

        Set RangeToCopy = CurrentWorkSheet.Range("N7:N" & DataFileLastRow)

        'To insert rows before pasting into new rows
        If RangeToCopy.Rows.Count > 1 Then
            '-1 to counter the +2 below so that the additional rows are added below the first row in MasterFile
            For DataFileRowCount = 1 To RangeToCopy.Rows.Count - 1
                MasterFileSheet.Range("C" & MasterFileLastRow + 2).EntireRow.Insert xlDown
            Next DataFileRowCount
        End If

        'Use this code to paste the values from DataFile to MasterFile
        RangeToCopy.Copy MasterFileSheet.Range("C" & MasterFileLastRow + 1 & _
                                              ":C" & MasterFileLastRow + 1 + RangeToCopy.Rows.Count)

        'Use this code if you want to transpose
                                                    '+1 here allows you to insert to the next unused line
        'MasterFileSheet.Range("C" & MasterFileLastRow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, _
                                                                    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

    Next CurrentWorkSheet

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Jean.. Your code works great. Thank you so much. I need one more help on this,                                                                                                         In my master, I assign only one cell for this value (N7),                                       It It's more than one cell means, I need to insert a row in my master and then the next cell value will be in the inserted row. Weather it's possible with your code.? please help me if you find time.

Comment: @Divya do you want to copy the entire row or do you want to copy it across the data from col N onwards and then paste it in column C

Comment: Ok, so you need to transpose the additional values from Column N into the row in the master file

Comment: @Divya check now

Comment: Hi Jean, Your code has done lot to me. But at this moment, one more task need to do with your code.                                                                Your code is new to me. But it works great, so I want to use your code. Will you please help me?                                                                            The concern is, In my Datafile, if the value to be is only i cell N7, that should directly paste on Maste. If  the range is N7:N10, It should insert  the rows in my master for the additional 3 rows & then it should paste. Will you please try?

Comment: @Divya check now

Comment: Hi, Jean. With your help, I've tried what exactly I need, But still I couldn't get it. So again I come to you. What I exactly need is,                 If the RangeToCopy is equal to one cell, then it Should directly paste into Master,    If the RangeToCopy is > 1, then it should get the First cell of Data into my available cell in master directly and then, it should insert the rows in master below for the next available rows in Datasheet. Will you please help me if you find time for this final output?

Comment: @Divya thats exactly what it does. I have changed it a bit to insert only the additional rows. After this you need to figure out the code and then modify it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

HI Divya The below code may be helpful to u

```
Sub Selectvalue()
   Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
Lastrow = Workbooks("Mastersheet").Sheets("sheet1").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Workbooks("Mastersheet").Sheets("sheet1").Range("C" & Lastrow).Offset(1, 0) = ws.Range("N7:N" & Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row)
Next ws
End Sub
```